# What is the correct ssl certificates configuration for multiple domain/sub-domains/servers?

Tags: iis-8, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to configure SSL certificate with Let's Encrypt, but after configuring, some customers complained about "Privacy Error", specifically, one error was ERR_INVALID_CERT. 
Most of the complaints came from Chrome on Android. 
Windows 7 and up rendered green bar.
Windows XP SP3 - rendered the error, but after manually importing the certs to the customer's PC, it rendered green.

My setup is on two servers:

Server A has: www.masterclub.es, es.octopon.me, ...

Server B has: www.masterclub.co.il, octopon.me, ...

I issued an SSL certificate with let's encrypt, that contains all of the domain names, and bound it to all the sites.

Some time before this trouble, I used the certificate only on Server B, and there were no complaints. So my suspicion is regarding the use of the same SSL certificate, on two different servers (and IP's), whose reverse DNS records are different as well.

Please advise on the correct strategy of deploying ssl certificate(s) - should I issue one per server, or one per each domain, or one for all is enough, or is it something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let's encrypt changed from X1 to X3. The server kept the old certificate, and that what was causing the privacy errors.
Here is are the details and how to fix:
https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/what-is-the-correct-ssl-certificates-configuration-for-multiple-domain-sub-domains-servers/23781